# extract patches from images with python

Tags: python, image, extract, patch

I have an image and I want to extract 6 patches

I tried sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d but the result is not what I need and I can't see any other parameter like e.g stride.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Using https://github.com/samdobson/image_slicer

Do:

```
import image_slicer
image_slicer.slice('image.jpg', 12)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's your lucky day, you can do that without writing any code using **ImageMagick** which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for macOS and Windows. So, in the Terminal (Command Prompt on Windows) starting with this 2048x1536 image:

[image]

You can run:

```
magick image.png -crop 512x512 slice-%02d.png
```

which gives you 12 slices, each 512x512:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3205 23 Jan 18:45 slice-00.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3205 23 Jan 18:45 slice-01.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3205 23 Jan 18:45 slice-02.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3205 23 Jan 18:45 slice-03.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3148 23 Jan 18:45 slice-04.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3148 23 Jan 18:45 slice-05.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3148 23 Jan 18:45 slice-06.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3148 23 Jan 18:45 slice-07.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3239 23 Jan 18:45 slice-08.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3239 23 Jan 18:45 slice-09.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3239 23 Jan 18:45 slice-10.png
-rw-r--r--@ 1 mark  staff  3239 23 Jan 18:45 slice-11.png
```

And if we montage them all together again on a yellow background, you'll get:

```
magick montage -background yellow -geometry +10+10 slice* montage.png
```

[image]

---

If you are on **ImageMagick** v6 or older, use:

```
convert image.png -crop 512x512 slice-%02d.png
```

and

```
montage -background yellow -geometry +10+10 slice* montage.png
```